# How to deploy a Mono console app on Mac?

Tags: macos, deployment, mono, console-application, xamarin-studio

I wrote a C# console app using a new *Console Project* in Xamarin Studio. Now, how do I deploy it without requiring other users to manually install Mono on their machines? Ideally, I'd like to just distribute a binary executable (not using the Mac App Store).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the mkbundle tool to include all dependencies within your binary. Scroll down to "Bundles" in the below link.

[http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aRunning_Mono_Applications)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it generates an error. It tries to find `mono-2.pc` which I don't seem to have (using the latest Mono stable version). Here's the error: `Compiling:
as -o temp.o temp.s 
cc -g -o hello -Wall temp.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2`  temp.o
Package mono-2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `mono-2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'mono-2' found
temp.c:1:10: fatal error: 'mono/metadata/mono-config.h' file not found
#include <mono/metadata/mono-config.h>
`